# PHP Parse ini file

Tags: php, arrays, ini

I wrote a program to skim log files and pass the information into an ini file and I'm trying to do some php work with it, **I have 0 experience with php.**

I have an INI file that contains information like so,

```
[76561197962467705]
Username = ".buckisM"
Suicide = 0
bear.prefab = 0
killed by fall = 0
patrolhelicopter.prefab = 0
wolf.prefab = 0
Cold = 0
Explosion = 0
barricade = 0
Player Deaths = 0
Total Deaths = 0
Kills = 2
```

I use the php ini parser and can get the ini to print to a webpage.

```
    $ini_array = parse_ini_file("myfile.ini", true);
    print_r($ini_array);
```

The printed array.
http://liveviewtest.byethost7.com/index.php

From what I have read parse_ini_file parses the information into a multidimensional array if the true flag is set. Why cant I access the array elements using brackets?

```
echo $ini_array[0][0];
```

Comment: What you are trying to fetch from this array'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what you got is actually a dictionary, which is a non ordered array. You can't address each element of that structure by a numeric index, since it is indexed with the keys defined in the ini file. You address it like

```
$ini_array['76561197988912576']['username']
```

You can cycle with a foreach loop

```
foreach($ini_array as $key=>$value) {
  echo ($value['username']);
}
```

Or you can convert your dictionary into an indexed array with "array_keys"

```
$ini_array = array_keys($ini_array);
echo $ini_array[0]['username'];
```

Comment: Is there no way to cycle through it? The ini file is continually growing and the numbers constantly changing.

Answer (score 0):

Because in this case you have `hash` with string keys. For example if you want get first `Username` from this array you can try this code:

```
var_dump($ini_array['76561197988912576']['Username']);
```

I hope it help.